# Is it acceptable to post a duplicate or very similar answer to non-identical duplicate questions on different SE sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Typically, this would involve duplicate questions. I searched SO-Meta to see if this question was already answered, and I found a few, but they all related to answering questions duplicated on the same SE site.

In this case, I'm talking about duplicate or near duplicate questions found on *different* SE sites. And to be clear, I'm *not* talking about cases where the same user might cross post the same question on multiple SE sites. I mean 2 questions by different users and not obviously copy-pasted from one to the other, but still essentially duplicates.

I don't have any specific examples at hand, but I've seen questions on Stack Overflow or Super User or Server Fault or Programmers.SE, and seen a duplicate or near duplicate on one of the other sites. I'm talking duplicate to the extent that sometimes they could both be answered with the same answer.

So my question is, if I can answer the question, is it OK to post the same or nearly same answer to the questions on both sites, or should I make significant efforts to hide the fact that the answers are the same?

Answer (score 4):

When I'm doing it, I'll just include a link to the other answer, with a few sentences quoted for those who don't like following links.  That way the bulk of the answer stays in one place, and its clear that they really are the same answer.

If they are actually duplicate questions on the different sites (and not different questions that happen to share an answer), flag one of them for a mod to do something.